# "Create a new account for an anonymous order" Rule issue with required field

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).
I have enabled the anonymous user to access checkout and place an order. 
There is this rule available in Drupal commerce("Create a new account for an anonymous order") that creates an account for user's who do not have an account and checkout anonymously.

**The Problem** is that there is an image field which is required in the user account form. So due this, it is having issue creating a new user, as I am not able to supply a value to it. I have set a default image, but its still having the same issue.

Anyone knows how to set this default image or make it non-required to add image while creating account through rules?

[image: "Create a new account for an anonymous order" Rule]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Make the field not required at the field level but then use a Form alter hook to make it required when presenting the form.
2. Make the logo point to the default image by setting the data value to `public://your-file-here.png` inside of the rule.

Comment: Will you please elaborate, how I can implement the option 2, when I am trying to set path of image on this field it is returning "Data selector image_path for parameter param_field_field_name is invalid".

Comment: as you suggested in option 1, I made the field not required from, and then I wrote form_alter() to make the field required. It worked thanks